# SSRS title changing expression

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

Hello guys i need to create title expresion in report builder which:

will change name from "x" to "first 100x" when count of all rows in table will reach 100...

any ideas ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

`=IIF(CountRows("MyDataSet")=100,"First 100x","x")`

Comment: That works, really big thanks, you are great :)